# How to check if CGPoints in array have the identical coordinates?

Tags: arrays, swift, cgpoint

Is it possible to check if CGPoints in array have the identical x/y coordinates?

Here is the code.

```
enum Three {
   case pointOne(point: CGPoint)
   case pointTwo(point: CGPoint)
   case pointThree(point: CGPoint)

   func coordinatesXY() -> [CGPoint] {
       switch self {
           case .pointOne(let point): return [point]
           case .pointTwo(let point): return [point]
           case .pointThree(let point): return [point]
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `==`

```
enum Three {
 case pointOne(point: CGPoint)
 case pointTwo(point: CGPoint)
 case pointThree(point: CGPoint)

   func coordinatesXY() -> CGPoint {
      switch self {
       case .pointOne(let point): return point
       case .pointTwo(let point): return point
       case .pointThree(let point): return point
    }
  }
}


let point1 = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

if point1 == point2{
   print("yes")
  }

 Three.pointOne(point: point1).coordinatesXY() //Gives you a CGPoint
 Three.pointTwo(point: point2)

func checkEquality(pointA : CGPoint, pointB : CGPoint){

       if Three.pointOne(point: pointA).coordinatesXY() == Three.pointTwo(point: pointB).coordinatesXY(){
         print("yes") //Prints yes
  }


}

//Prototype of comparing two coordinates

var arrOne = [Three]()
var arrTwo = [Three]()

 arrOne.append(Three.pointOne(point: point1))
 arrOne.append(Three.pointOne(point: point1))
 arrOne.append(Three.pointOne(point: point1))
 arrOne.append(Three.pointOne(point: point1))
 arrOne.append(Three.pointOne(point: point1))
 arrOne.append(Three.pointOne(point: point1))

 arrTwo.append(Three.pointTwo(point: point2))
 arrTwo.append(Three.pointTwo(point: point2))
 arrTwo.append(Three.pointTwo(point: point2))
 arrTwo.append(Three.pointTwo(point: point2))
 arrTwo.append(Three.pointTwo(point: point2))
 arrTwo.append(Three.pointTwo(point: point2))



for eachA in arrOne{

  let arrayOneElement = eachA.coordinatesXY()
    for eachB in arrTwo{
       let arrayTwoElement = eachB.coordinatesXY()
        checkEquality(arrayOneElement, pointB: arrayTwoElement)
   }
}
```

Comment: But if I don't know coordinates 'cause I'm dragging points with mouse.

Comment: Could you write for-in loop for this?

Comment: I create cgpoints with IBAction func, then position them with mouse. After that I create xml file for other app. XML data must have xy coordinates of every point. If any points has identical coordinates they share the same id.

Comment: to receive the sequence of coordinates I use: var array: [Three] = []